# Passing input value into name of input

Tags: php, forms, input, get

I'm trying to get the value from two input fields and pass them as the name in a form.

In my code, I am hardcoding the value of the price range in for testing purposes.

```
      echo 'PRICE RANGE:';
        echo 'Low: <input type="text" name="t[pr_100000]" value="" maxlength="25" /> High: <input type="text" name="t[ph_10000000]" value="" maxlength="25" />';

        echo 'STATUS:';
       $termsStatus = get_terms( 'Status', array(
              'hide_empty' => 0
              ) );
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($termsStatus as $term_st) {
                $termsStatus = $term_st->name . 'PropertyFilter';
                echo '<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="t[st_' . $term_st->name . ']"  value="st_">' .$term_st->name. '</label></li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
```

Here is the code on another page that the search parameters are sent to:

```
// GETS THE VARIABLE FROM THE SEARCH WIDGET
    $array_terms_test = array_keys( $_GET['t'] );
```

Any suggetions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to ask the question.

Comment: I've edited the code. The issue is how do I get the values from the price input and then pass them as the name"___" so it is in the url? The second snippit of code grabs the url and extracts the info. That works but I need it to be passed from the form to the url. It is working in the Status section. Please let me know if you have any questions and thanks again!

Comment: Can't you just do `value="st_' . $term_st->name . '">' .$term_st->name. '` ?? If thats what you meant..

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment, it seems like you are having trouble passing the input fields to the second snippit of code (via a submit button or javascript). You need to surround the input fields with a form tag and submit the form. If you want to use $_GET simply assign action='get' on the form.  If for some reason this doesn't work for you, you can use javascript to pull the values from the fields and create a url var which you use to redirect (window.location = url).

Sorry if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: There is a form tag. The form works right now. I'm just building onto it. It will be a filter for properties. I'm trying to filter by price like a range. So the first text field and the second text field for price need to be grabbed and then inserted into the url. It is already doing that for the checkboxes.

Comment: Submitting the form inserts the data into the URL.  If its doing it for the checkboxs properly then it should do it for the price field as well.  The only reasons I can think that it would not is 1) they are not in the form or 2) The values are empty